# visual studio C++ summary подсветка

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Есть ли возможность сделать подсветку summary-комментариев в Visual Studio C++?

Сейчас все комментарии монотонны:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу чтобы например теги выделялись синим или как-то так

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tcbhat.CppTripleSlash-xmldoccommentsforc

Comment: [Better comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments)

Comment: @user7860670 Здравствуйте, я не совсем понимаю как это настроить. Я скачал расширение, установил, оно отображается в списке установленных, но подсветки нету

Comment: Если открыть настройки Tools → Options → Environment → Fonts and colors, то там будут пункты для цветов XML Doc Comments.